# How to write unit test for user-detail with router.register base name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

This error appears when I write a test for user-detail, I thought the error from `response = self.client.get(reverse('user-detail',kwargs={'pk':1}))`, I used router.register to config ulrs base name, and that makes me confused when writing the test. So in this case, where the point in my code was wrong?

```py
    def test_list_user_detail(self):
        """
            List user detail
        """
        self.client.post(self.url, self.data, format='json')
        resp = self.client.post(
            '/auth/token/login/', data={'email': 'Foo@gmail.com', 'password': 'Boo'}, format='json')
        token = resp.data['auth_token']
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='token '+token)

        response = self.client.get(reverse('user-detail',kwargs={'pk':1}))
        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_list_user_detail (sellHouse.tests.UserTest)
List user detail
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code\restfullapi\example\sellHouse\tests.py", line 68, in test_list_user_detail
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Try print response.data : `{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Not found.', code='not_found')}`

Comment: Could you show urls?

Comment: ```py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, basename='user')
```

Comment: Okay, are you sure that user has PK of 1? Because url is found, but when you are trying to access it, DRF returns 404 so there is no user with such PK

Comment: The error looks more like being caused by the user object not being found than the wrong URL. Maybe try to retrieve the user object in your test function and make sure the view can retrieve it.

Comment: fixed, because I wrote 2 test cases above, in each test case include the post for creating user, so pk id for this test should be = 3 :D. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not rely on the primary key value dispatch by the database. Tests can run in any order, and any subset of tests can run. Therefore it is possible that sometimes it is `3` whereas when you run the tests in a different order, or only a subset of the tests, it is `1`. Therefore you should work with the primary key of your database object, so for example:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            email='Foo@gmail.com', password='Boo'
        )

    def test_list_user_detail(self):
        """
            List user detail
        """
        self.client.post(self.url, self.data, format='json')
        resp = self.client.post(
            '/auth/token/login/', data={'email': 'Foo@gmail.com', 'password': 'Boo'}, format='json')
        token = resp.data['auth_token']
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='token '+token)

        response = self.client.get(reverse('user-detail',kwargs={'pk': self.user.pk}))
        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here we thus assign the created object to `self.user`, and then use `self.user.pk` when we determine the URL.